# Java - Large array advice on how to break it down

Tags: java, arrays, large-files, large-object-heap

I hope you're doing good.
I was making the code for a program that will be dealing with a large number of array elements. For example, array A[] will have all the words that start with a letter "a". Now, if i put all in one class the program can't run due to not enough memory. I was going to make each array its own class. But in general, is there a better way to approach this instead of arrays? Or any other advice to wrestle with the many elements? I might be looking at 500k-1.xmil elements in the whole thing.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't have enough memory for just 500k strings? How much to do you have? That's not a "large" array.

Comment: Putting arrays to different classes doesn't decrease the memory usage in any way. Use a database or other external datasource instead.

Comment: Currently having all the Strings in a single array object will take less memory than splitting it up into a bunch of smaller arrays

Comment: Well the test was done with a around 900k strings and I had around 3gb ram free, the script crashed and netbeans gave an error about insuffecient memory. So i threw 500k if i happen to reduce it to make it work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be trying to make it into 1 value of a big string for each array and split it later. If that doesnt work, i guess i have to go with a database.